# Get non existence arguments of SQL IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, in-operator

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column IN ('item1','item2','item3')
```

it's result contains item1 and item2, How can I get the non existence argument (**item3**)? 
Is it possible?

**EDIT:**
I have an array of items. every minute some new items are adding to the array.
So I should get new items that are new and doesn't exist in the table.
After that I can do my process and insert the new items to the table

Thanks

Comment: What is `non existence argument`?

Comment: You have to be clear on this one. Do you want to add a column with item3?

Comment: @dotnetom in this example it's "item3"

Comment: remove item 3 on condition

Comment: @ShayanKM Still it doesn't explain what do you mean by that? Do you want to add data sample and your expected results so we could understand what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @szakwani Well, I have an array of "items" and I want to have a list of new items, that doesn't exist in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will return the items that doesn't exist in MyTable:

```
WITH B
AS
(
    SELECT 'Item1' AS col
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Item2' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Item3' 

)
SELECT B.col
FROM B
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM MyTable T
        WHERE
            T.col = B.col
    )
```

EDIT:
Because of building such a select statement at the client side could be teddious and dangeours, you should take care of sql injection and formatting issues, I suggest you to use a table valued funtion like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Items
(
    item nvarchar(128) PRIMARY KEY
)

GO

CREATE FUNCTION GetNonExistingItems( @Items xml )
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
WITH B
AS
(
    SELECT c.value('.', 'nvarchar(128)') As item
    FROM @items.nodes('items/item') T(c)
)
SELECT B.item
FROM B
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Items I
        WHERE B.item = i.item

    )

GO

DECLARE @items XML = N'
<items>
    <item>Item1</item>
    <item>Item2</item>
    <item>Item5</item>
</items>'

SELECT *
FROM GetNonExistingItems (@Items)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked... it's somehow similar to what @Giorgi_Nakeuri wrote. but I'm not sure about these queries performance, is this the best way?

Comment: The performance is similar (if not equals) to LEFT JOIN WHERE MyTable.col IS NULL,

Answer (score 3):

You can do it if you translate your array to table like this:

```
Select * From 
( select 'item1' As Column
  union
  select 'item2' As Column
  union
  select 'item3' As Column
) l
left join Table t on l.Column = t.Column
Where t.Column is NULL
```

Version without union:

```
Select * From 
    ( VALUES
      ('Item1'),
      ('Item2'),
      ('Item3')  
    ) As l(Column)
    left join Table t on l.Column = t.Column
    Where t.Column is NULL
```

Comment: It did the job, but I think using "union select" Instead of "IN" would kill my performance... Isn't there any other better way?

Comment: Check new version of statement

Answer (score 2):

After reading your edit, i can suggest you the following approach. Because you want to insert non existing items into the table I think you could do it in one single merge statement

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Items
(
    item nvarchar(128) PRIMARY KEY
)
```

You could pass the new items in the array in xml form to the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertIfNotExists @Items xml
AS
    WITH B
    AS
    (
        SELECT c.value('.', 'nvarchar(128)') As item
        FROM @items.nodes('items/item') T(c)
    )
    MERGE INTO Items I
    USING B ON B.Item = I.Item
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (Item) VALUES (Item);

GO
```

Here you have a sample execution:

```
DECLARE @items XML = N'
<items>
    <item>Item1</item>
    <item>Item2</item>
    <item>Item3</item>
    <item>Item4</item>
</items>'

EXEC InsertIfNotExists @items
```

Another alternative to pass items to the stored procedure is using a table valued parameter instead of xml.

Comment: Thank you for your attention to the edit and +1. But I have a .NET process between the select and insert queries, so these shouldn't be combined.

Comment: Ok, I edited my previous answer to provide you what I think is a better aproach

Answer (score -1):

make a proc to return all existence then do it

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column NOT IN(your proc );
```